# both users log out if both logged in but different script

Tags: php, session, authentication

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:/index.php");
?>
```

Hi. I have a logout script that looks like this in my program. I have 2 users that logs in in my system, the Admin and the Customer. The problem is when both users are logged in and I click the logout link on for example in the customer page, both users log out. What's the solution for this problem? thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to say that when user A logs out (on a different computer) then user B is also logged out (on their separate computer)?

Comment: Shouldn't happen, unless those two "users" are you using a single browser to log in twice - that means they'd be sharing the same session ID.

Comment: you are using the same browser

Comment: Yes I am using the same browser. Sorry I didn't include that one in my problem. Is there a way to prevent the other user from logging out too while I'm on the same browser?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I am going to guess that you are testing both admin and customer on the same browser. If that is the case, then unless you are doing something like using Chrome's incognito window for one of them, you're saving the same `PHPSESSIONID` for both client and admin. That means calling `session_destroy();` for one calls `session_destroy();` for both.

Comment: Yes. I am testing both admin and customer side. So is there any coding solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If both users are logged on to the same computer using the same browser, then you are clearing the session data for the whole session by calling `session_destroy()`. In PHP session represents a one-to-one relationship between a user agent (browser) and the server.

I am having a hard time envisioning a practical system where two different people could be logged in through the same browser at the same time. Generally speaking, a login system deals with one user at a time. Compared to standard systems, you've got an unusual setup here. I would suggest re-thinking your login procedure so your system is only ever dealing with **one user per session**.

However, if it IS indeed possible for two users to be logged in simultaneously, then you'll need to keep track of their states in the `$_SESSION` variable separately. When one or the other logs out, rather than destroy the session, just clear the **state** for that user:

```
//logout.php
$logout_type = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : false;
// check for a bunk logout_type, redirect if type isn't valid
if ($logout_type === false || ($logout_type != 'user' && $logout_type != 'admin'))
  header("location:/index.php");

session_start();

// if this type's state isn't even set, then this isn't valid
if (isset($_SESSION['login_state'][$logout_type]) || $_SESSION['login_state'][$logout_type] == false)
  header("location:/index.php");

//set the state as false
$_SESSION['login_state'][$logout_type] = false;
  header("location:/index.php");
```

When you link to your logout page, use `logout.php?type=user` or `logout.php?type=admin`.  When someone logs in, make sure to set the appropriate `login_state` session variable.

Now, anywhere you need to check for a login state, check like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login_state']['user']) && $_SESSION['login_state']['user'] == true) {
 /* user is logged on */
}
if (isset($_SESSION['login_state']['admin']) && $_SESSION['login_state']['admin'] == true) {
 /* admin is logged on */
}
```